# Rails Has One relation

Tags: ruby, associations

I have a simple database that has the following relation.

Each Server has one Game.

now the table Game is just a list of the different games that are possible to have on the server.

However, when I do a @server.game, I get a SQL exception because it's trying to find the server's INSTANCE of it's game (Select * from games where games.server_id = 1) I'd really like it just to do (select * from games where games.id = @server.game_id)

Any clues as to how to perform this association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Server` has a `belongs_to` association to `Game`, the underlying SQL will then be what your are looking for

Comment: while I feel completely retarded for not realizing that, I was simply being to literal with the associations.

Thanks!

Comment: In two years of Rails development I am yet to find a situation where has_one works better than belongs_to. That might just be me however...